# What is the proper way to implement contentview with constraints in a scrollview in xcode using autolayout?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, scrollview

Recently I'm testing to do a very complicated view in xcode using nothing but scrollview and programatically added imgviews. Like this

[image]

What I did is, I put a UIView called contentview in a scrollview and I then add a lots of ImageViews in the contentview. The real thing is much much complicated than the illustration so I can't use tableview. Sorry for the poor illustration but I think you will get the idea.

Everything is fine until I tried to add the last constraint in code, which marked red in the picture. When I did it, it breaks the entire chain of constraint.

In another word, this is working

```
V:|-[view1(30)]-[view2(30)]-[view3(30)]
```

This is not

```
V:|-[view1(30)]-[view2(30)]-[view3(30)]-|
```

And btw, what is the proper way to do it anyway? I tried to add imageviews directly into the scrollview itself but I can't make the view to use autolayout like this

```
H:|-[view]-|  The superview here is a scrollview
```

The result, this view will be very narrow in width. I guess scrollview doesn't have a width value or sth? that's my guessing. That's why I added a contentview as a holder for all the imageviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I did my own work.

The key to make scrollview and contentview and everythin else inside work automatically using nothing but autolayout is this.

1, Manually add scrollview to self.view, and a contentview to scrollview. Set both scrollview and contentview to setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

2, set scrollview to H:|[scrollview]| and V:|[scrollview]|, set contentview to be  H:|[contentview]| and V:|[contentview]|

3, Now try to add Views to content view and set their constraints to the contentview. You should see that when the views are larger than the current window size, the scrollview started to scroll. IE, this setting will automatically set the scrollview.contentSize using autolayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work. - http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

To summarize -

1. Add scroll view to main view.
2. Add a UIView (lets call it content view) to scroll view.
3. Now add all your views to the above UIView.

For each of them set the constraints so as the separation on all sides is 0. And finally add equal height and equal width constraints between the content view and the main view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but those recommended steps are the ones I took. I guess if I need to let the autolayout to work out the contentsize of the scrollview, I'll have to set the scrollview to not auto translate into constraints too. I'll test it later